# Trying to show information in the frontend

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to print my information that i sent in my frontend but it does not showing nothing , i do not know whats going on,my query is fine because when i print in console its works fine

https://snag.gy/tVXbdg.jpg

**MY TS**

```
export class HomePage {
  options:BarcodeScannerOptions;
  encodText:string='';
  resul:string;
  encodedData:any={};
  scannedData:any={};
  public resultado: string;

  public product=[];
  // public product= {};

public resultadoref: firebase.database.Reference = firebase.database().ref('/productos');

  constructor(public fdb: AngularFireDatabase,public navCtrl: NavController,
  public scanner:BarcodeScanner,private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

  }

  public cargarvalor(){
    var that= this;
    var referenceresultado= this.resultadoref.orderByChild('Producto').equalTo(this.resultado);
    referenceresultado.on('value', function(snapshot){
    var data = snapshot.val();
    that.product= snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);


    // this.product=snapshot.val();
    });
  }
```

***MY HOME.HTML***

Buscar

```
<div class="row header">
      <div class="col">Producto</div>
      <div class="col">Descripcion</div>
      <div class="col">Precio</div>
    </div>
{{ product.Producto }} {{ product.Valor }} {{ product.Descripcion }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing them in

```
 <h1>< {{ product.Producto }} {{ product.Valor }}</h1>
```